# Assert one from multiple entries in one CDK property

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I need to assert, as part of my TDD, that specific `Stage` in CodePipeline got created.
Tried to use CDK's method but I can't get this code working to retreive only specific `Name` from all `Stages` array.

Sample data:

```
"Type": "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline",
 "Properties": {
   "RoleArn": {
     "Fn::GetAtt": [
       "PipelineRoleABC",
       "Arn"
     ]
   },
   "Stages": [
     {
       "Actions": [
         {...}
       ],
       "Name": "Source"
     },
     {
       "Actions": [
         {...}
       ],
       "Name": "Build"
     }
    ]
   }
```

I want to assert if `Name: Build` exists in the code.

```
template.has_resource_properties("AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline", {"Stages": [assertions.Match.object_like({"Name": "Build"})]})
```

Currently getting an error:

```
Expected array of length 1 but received 3 at /Properties/Stages (using objectLike matcher)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Capture` class helped:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.assertions/README.html#capturing-values

```
    capture_stages = assertions.Capture()
    template.has_resource_properties("AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline", {
        "Stages": capture_stages
    })

    capture_stages_as_array = capture_stages.as_array()

    try:
        next(item for item in capture_stages_as_array if item["Name"] == "TestEnv")
    except:
        print("Missing stage!")
```